# Natbib: create shortened citation call-out when author is a group with a long name

Tags: citing, natbib

I am creating a .bib file with my references and using the package `natbib`.
One of my references is a research group; let's say for example that the name is "WAWO scientific research group". I would like that when using `\cite{reference}` it showed "WAWO 2016", while the references at the end showed "WAWO scientific research group, 2016... Blabla".

Writing just `"author = {WAWO scientific research group}"` shows "Group 2016" when using `\cite`.

Writing `"author = {{WAWO scientific research group}}"` writes the full name when using `\cite.`

Any ideas? I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you could create a citation "alias" for the entry in question. Use `\defcitealias` to set up the alias and `\citetalias` and `\citepalias` to generate citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{wawo:16,
    author = {{WAWO Scientific Research Group}},
    year   = 2016,
    title  = {The {WAWO Report}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\defcitealias{wawo:16}{WAWO 2016}

\begin{document}
\citetalias{wawo:16}, \citepalias{wawo:16}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Thanks also for editing my question. I typed it from my cell phone while breastfeeding my baby XD

Comment: @Titianne - You're most welcome! And you're a brave multitasker to boot! :-)